# Query TFS 2013 to get recently automated

Tags: automated-testing, visualstudio, tfs2010

I want to find a method to query our TFS Server 2013 for test cases that have been switched from "Not Automated" or "Planned" to "Automated" within a given time period.  I know I can create a query in Visual Studio that would pull all automated cases, and can add `"Changed Date" > @today - 30` as a clause, but the methods that some of the manual QA testers user to update and change test cases end up pulling in a lot more than just the recently automated.  Is there a way to create a sub query on the History field or query the cube directly for this information?

Here's what I have so far:

[image: A screen shot of my automation query]

Comment: So far, it looks like the only way to do this is to create a report using the TFS data warehouse.  It doesn't look like the Visual Studio IDE provides a method to do this.

Answer (score 1):

[TFS now has a REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/overview) that you can engage with.

There are some sample queries that you can perhaps find out the information you want [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/queries).